# Double HTTP call to server with different METHOD

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, http-method

My ex-colleague left some angular.js code to save some data to database via a `HTTP POST`.

```
factory.save=function(data){
    var deferred=$q.defer();

    $http({
        url:'http://localhost/saveData',
        method:"POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data:data
    }).success(function(result){
        //success
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When I exam the web traffic between the UI and API Server, I see the `saveData` API was called twice. The first call is using request method `OPTIONS` and the second one is `POST` as expected. I searched throughout the UI code and don't find any API call to `saveData` with method = `OPTIONS`. Is this something built in `$http`? How do I save this hit to the API server?

Comment: btw, it's `OPTIONS`, not `OPTION`

Comment: See [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: Thank all! This clears.